# SimpleDateFormat not catching invalid 13th month

Tags: java, validation, simpledateformat

I am attempting to validate a query parameter for a date. If an invalid date is entered i return an 400 BAD_REQUEST response code. However, my validation is not catching an invalid date of '201113'. It does however, catch an invalid year such as '000012'.
I am using the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymm"); 
    df.setLenient(false);
    try
    {
        df.parse(endDate);
        df.parse(startDate);
    }
    catch(ParseException e)
    {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

I know that setting lenient to false should have fixed this problem, but it persists.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"mm" is for minutes. "MM" is for months... Try "yyyyMM" as your format string instead.